# How can I start Zookeper and Kafka both at the same time?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper

I wrote a python app that uses Kafka to share data between producer and consumer. I am going to dockerize it and so I wrote the dockerfile. The problem is in the final steps, when I run the Zookeeper server, it says binding to port .... and it never exits, so that it would be possible to run Kafka server also.

```
FROM  ubuntu:18.04
ADD app.py /

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

RUN  apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y wget \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get install gzip

RUN  apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y default-jdk \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN wget http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/kafka/2.2.0/kafka_2.11-2.2.0.tgz

RUN tar -xvzf kafka_2.11-2.2.0.tgz
RUN cd kafka_2.11-2.2.0 \
&& ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties \
&& ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server.properties 


CMD [ “python”, “.app.py”]
```

Comment: Can you try run those server start scripts with nohup?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I read about it and I think it is only for processes that end, while I don't think in my case the process will end. Moreover, I need them to run in parallel.

Comment: On my docker image I run SSH and HTTPD with supervisor, you could give that a go

Comment: Typically you run one program per container; ZooKeeper, Kafka, and your application should be in three separate containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would only need to create a container for your own application. There are already numerous containers available for Kafka and Zookeeper.

A suggestion would be to run a simple Kafka stack using **docker compose** and then either start your application externally (for instance via command-line or IDE) or create a docker container and run it.

A simple Kafka stack with just Kafka and Zookeeper would require a simple docker-compose file with the following (of course you will need to have docker-compose installed on your system):

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.0.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0-2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
```

If you put the above in a file named simple-kafka-stack.yml, you can execute it by running the command:

```
docker-compose -f simple-kafka-stack.yml up
```

Comment: can you say what can cause this type of error? ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

Comment: Hard to say specifically, as there are a lot of issues with the Docker daemon/service. Personally, I would remove the currently installed docker-compose and then install the latest one, following the instructions in the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).